# floating point number comparison in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to compare floating point number by `-gt` but it says that point expecting integer value. That means it can not handle floating point number . Then i tried the following code

```
chi_square=4
if [ "$chi_square>3.84" | bc ]
then
echo yes
else
echo no
fi
```

But the output is wrong with error . Here is the out put-

```
line 3: [: missing `]'
File ] is unavailable.
no
```

Here the `no` is echoed but it should be `yes`. I think that's because of the error it's showing. can anybody help me.

Comment: `bash` cannot handle floating point, but Korn shell (`ksh`) can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `bc` use it like this:

```
if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$chi_square>3.84") -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo 'yes'
else
   echo 'no'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
$ awk -v chi_square=4 'BEGIN{print (chi_square > 3.84 ? "yes" : "no")}'
yes

$ awk -v chi_square=3 'BEGIN{print (chi_square > 3.84 ? "yes" : "no")}'
no
```

or if you prefer avoiding ternary expressions for some reason (and also showing how to use a value stored in a shell variable):

```
$ chi_square=4
$ awk -v chi_square="$chi_square" 'BEGIN{
    if (chi_square > 3.84) {
        print "yes"
    }
    else {
        print "no"
    }
}'
yes
```

or:

```
$ echo "$chi_square" |
awk '{
    if ($0 > 3.84) {
        print "yes"
    }
    else {
        print "no"
    }
}'
yes
```

or to bring it full circle:

```
$ echo "$chi_square" | awk '{print ($0 > 3.84 ? "yes" : "no")}'
yes
```